# Yosemite Laravel Setup with MCrypt

Tags: php, homebrew, osx-yosemite, mcrypt

Been at this for hours. What's annoying is that all of my files seem to be identical to what they were when using Mavericks. I've changed all the necessary parts to meet Yosemite's standards but I still get the error message - 'MCrypt PHP Extension Required'. My files are below

```
# php --ini 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-memcached.ini

.bash_profile
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

My installations were all through Brew, here's my brew list

```
ant     composer    icu4c       libmemcached    mcrypt      php54       sphinx
autoconf    freetype    jpeg        libpng      memcached   php54-mcrypt    unixodbc
automake    gettext     libevent    libtool     mhash       php54-memcached zlib
```

Any help would be loved!

Edit: I can't just add 'extension=mcrpyt.so' to my php.ini modules as I'll get the following error message -

```
#php --ini
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
    Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.4
    Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini
    Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d
    Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini,
    /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-memcached.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

just install [bitnami mamp stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/mamp), it include mcrypt extension.

Answer (score 0):

I [got this to guide to work for me](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-development-server/) and now have mcrypt running on Apache running under Yosemite.

The only thing to watch for if you follow this guide is that there are a couple of terminal commands that refer to the wrong php tar file or directory, eg tar -zxvf php-**5.5.9**.tar.gz should be tar -zxvf php-5.5.14.tar.gz

Other than that it worked like a charm. The only thing I'm not 100% sure about is whether or not you need to have Xcode installed first. If you don't and something doesn't work for you [get Xcode free download from iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12)

Good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to reinstall php with one line:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5
```